# What is the Senju clan's speciality?

Tags: naruto

Is it wood style? If yes, then how come only Hashirama can use it?

There has to be some special power that all the members of the Senju clan possessed, or else how could they be the greatest rivals to the Uchiha (who had Sharingan) who defeated every other clan other than the Senju?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is wood style. I don't really know why he's the only one that got itm but I think he was just lucky being born with it.

Comment: I think the answer is a combination of both Ero Sennin and Chronarchitect's answers.

Answer (score 6):

The only Senju to showcase the Wood Release was Hashirama Senju. You could say that the Wood Release was Hashirama's speciality. Even his brother Tobirama did not use Wood Release all that much, but instead had a variety of speciality techniques including Space-time jutsu, Edo Tensei, Kage Bunshin, etc.

The Uchiha are adept at using fire techniques, because of their natural affinity towards it. The Senju are commonly called as **"Senju clan of the forest"**. So we could only assume from the name that they are adept at using forest related skills; Wood Release.

But from the Senju we have seen in battle, namely Tobirama, Hashirama and Tsunade, the common feature about them is their unique fighting style and skills. This would lead into a more agreeable assumption. The clan's name, "Senju", literally means **"a thousand skills"**. So this would mean, rather than the whole clan specializing in one type of jutsu/technique/nature release/skill, the clan members would be specialized in different types of jutsu. This actually fits the meaning of their name. Which means, there isn't a trademark clan ability. This assumption is supported by the Senju we've seen in battle multiple times.

The Uchiha hadn't defeated all the other clans. It was just said that they were among the top powerful clans, only challenged by the Senju. The Uchiha and Senju had been fighting against each other over centuries, even before Hashirama and Madara's times. This was because of the Indra and Asura feud. So while the Uchiha were powerful, the only clan able to go against them were the descendants of Asura. That's the main reason as to why they could go toe to toe.

**TL;DR** : The Senju clan doesn't have a trademark ability. But all its members have proficiency in different types of jutsu. Because of being the descendants of the Sage of Six Paths' sons, the Senju and Uchiha were able to go toe to toe against each other.

Comment: But one thing this doesn't explain this is, Uchiha defeated every other clan with special abilities, but it could not defeat Senju, which didn't have a special ability to start with..how can that be justified?

Comment: Can you please provide reference to where it's being said that the Uchiha defeated all the other clans?

Comment: I think what he meant is that in one of the flashback it was said that Uchiha and Senju are the strongest clans. Which makes him think that other than Senju, Uchiha has defeated all the other clans, while it was just that they are stronger than the other clans and doesn't necessarily mean that they have defeated them.

Comment: yes I mean that, maybe they didn't defeat all the clans but they WERE stronger than all of them other than the Senju. What makes Senju so special that even tho they don't have any kind of kekei-genkai, they could still overpower the uchiha?

Comment: Here's the actual fact. The Uchiha and Senju had been fighting against each other over centuries, even before Hashirama and Madara's times. This was because of the Indra and Asura feud. So while the Uchiha were powerful, the only clan able to go against them were the descendants of Asura. That's the main reason as to why they could go toe to toe. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Senju are the descendants of the younger son of the **Sage of Six Paths**.

The Sage of six paths had two sons, the elder son inherited the sage's eyes  and his descendants, the *Uchiha*, inherit the dōjutsu kekei-genkai *Sharingan*.

And the younger son inherited his "body", granting him a powerful life force and chakra. His descendants are the Senju clan who possess more chakra compared to other shinobi clans.

So, the Senju clan doesn't possess any trademark ability other than having greater chakra.

Comment: Wrong. Indra inherited the Sharingan. Not Rinnegan.

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  The Senju side inherited the raw power and the strength of will/endurance.  The Uchiha side inherited the genius and technique (eyes).  They were, almost literally, two sides of the same coin, in natural opposition and balance to each other.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with "just large chakra reserves". If you've seen what Asura was capable of, then obviously his descendants would be having his potential. Overlooking that potential and focusing on just the "chakra storage" is somewhat underestimated.

Answer (score 0):

The descendants of the senju clan only inherit the Yang element innately and their physical abilities, restiveness, physical strength, etc ...

The other abilities have to do with the handling of each person, in the special case of Hashirama, him doesn't  inherit the element wood, but it is the creator of this technique, is the first to obtain this element.

The wood element is a Kekkei Genkai, but there are three forms of Kekkei Genkai. In the case of Hashirama he is the only user because he is the creator and the only one who manages to dominate it, in the manga is not explained, but is given to understand that no one inherits his skills or does not develop them. ( nothing is known about his son)

But it is known that these skills can be taught if genes are inherited as is the case of the Onoki dust element.